# Where is the set of repositories to search defined in the Dependencies report of the Maven Project Info Reports Plugin?

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project that has a dependency on another internal project. At this stage, the version is feature branch snapshot.

When the maven-project-info-reports-plugin generates its "Dependencies" report, it tries to look up the version in several public repositories (see log), eventually failing to do so. I have not configured those repos, neither in the global settings.xml nor in my private one, so where do they come from? How do I get rid of them?
The [goal documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html) does not mention any parameter that sets the repos to check.

Apparently, this happens to snapshots only. I run mvn from the command line on Ubuntu.

Log snippet:

```
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report  --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.4.1:dependencies
Downloading from cdh.snapshots.repo: https://repository.confluent.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mycompany/myproject/feature-XYZ-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from java.net2: http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/mycompany/myproject/feature-XYZ-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from version99: http://version99.qos.ch/com/mycompany/myproject/feature-XYZ-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from jitpack.io: https://jitpack.io/com/mycompany/myproject/feature-XYZ-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.mycompany:myproject:feature-XYZ-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to cdh.snapshots.repo (https://repository.confluent.com/content/repositories/snapshots): Transfer failed for https://repository.confluent.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mycompany/myproject/feature-XYZ-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

Comment: Probably from the POM of a dependency. If you want to avoid this kind of behaviour, you need to set a `<mirror>` in the `settings.xml`.

Comment: @JFabianMeier This explains why it is bad practice to use `<repositories>` in a POM.